# RenderTransform animation strangely not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a rectangle which I want to animate the angle on, from 0-180 degrees.

I'm doing this from code-behind rather than in XAML.
I have everything set up, but when I trigger the animation - nothing happens! I have checked multiple times and nothing is wrong! I really don't know what to do anymore.

Here is the code for the animation itself:

```
DoubleAnimation menuRktAngle = new DoubleAnimation();
menuRktAngle.From = 0;
menuRktAngle.To = 180;
menuRktAngle.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTarget(menuRktAngle, aniR);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(menuRktAngle, new PropertyPath((Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));

menubtnStoryboard.Children.Add(menuRktAngle);

menubtnStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

And the XAML code for the rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FF707070" Height="15" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center" x:Name="aniR">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_arrow_left}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
```

I tried manually setting the transform-angle and it works just fine. So there must be something wrong with the animation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because you try to animate a property that is not there yet. The property RenderTransform property of the Rectangle doesn't contain a RotateTransform. Set this in your XAML with a default value of 0, and my guess is, you will be able to animate it.

Add this to your XAML:

```
<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
</Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: I just tested it, and my answer is correct. Add this to your XAML: 

`<Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
 </Rectangle.RenderTransform>`

Comment: That did make sense actually. Haha I've been trying to solve this for atleast one hour. Thank you.

Comment: @jim - +1 but I would suggest to add the comment to your answer so that it can help others as well. (Generally people don't read comments).